# HTML inside a Fragment Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, html, webview, navigation, fragment

Im totally new on android development but i cant understand the code, i just dont know where to add WebView code.

My source code, has Fragments and each fragmen its XML, but where to add webview to load Local HTML for each fragment?, inm trying to writte a GameGuide in offline mode, i already havce it in HTML just need to put it inside the Code.

Thank You:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/WebViewHeroes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

}

**EDIT:**

After reading i found the error, i was calling HOME (default layout) everytime overlapping my new layout.

created heroes.xml and called it by deafult, then changed the code to load URL, coded finished is here

```
public class HeroesFragment extends Fragment {

    public HeroesFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.heroes, container, false);
        WebView heroespage = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.heroeswiki);
        heroespage.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hola.html");
       return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I got the best result doing like this:

```
String HTML = "Some HTML resource";  
WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, HTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The settings part was needed to show special characters.

In the example above I dynamically generate a WebView and then add it to my layout. For your case, the code should look like this:

```
public class HeroesFragment extends Fragment {

    public HeroesFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewHeroes);
        String HTML = "Some HTML resource";
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, HTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Now I do not know if you plan to show several different HTML pages in the same fragment, but then you simply issue `loadDataWithBaseURL` with another HTML resource.

Further, if you need support for javascript, zooming, etc. you will have to add those settings to the WebView before loading.

Comment: Didnt worked, posted here the full code by you and what i got

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did it crash, or not show anything, or.. ?

Answer (score 2):

In your `Fragment`s after you have got your `View rootView` variable in `onCreateView()`, do the following:

```
// Get your HTML
String yourHTML = "<p>Some <b>html</b> you have somewhere</p>";

// Get a handle on your webview
WebView webViewHeroes = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.WebViewHeroes);

// Populate webview with your html
webViewHeroes.loadData(yourHTML, "text/html", null);
```

**EDIT**

My answer uses a String with HTML in it. You are actually wanting to load an html file into the webview (which is different).

So, instead use this:

```
// Populate webview with your html
webViewHeroes.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hola.html");
```

Comment: Didnt worked, posted here the full code by you and what i got

Comment: Note on update: if you are having issues with permissions in KitKat, you could explore `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead, but let's see if we can get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

so in the `getView()` of the HeroesFragment you do the following

`if (rootView){
     WebView v = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.WebViewHeroes);
}`

and then you can just v. and do whatever you would like.